# AWS datapipeline copy from RDS to S3 fails with CommunicationLinkFailure

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, amazon-data-pipeline

I have an AWS data pipeline that copies data from RDS to S3 and runs every 15 minute.It runs fine but fails intermittently with error

> Unable to establish connection to jdbc:mysql://host.us-west >1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/db Communications link failure

I checked my mysql server configuration and it looks fine.

> wait_timeout                    | 28800
>
> connect_timeout                 | 10
>
> max_connections                 | 1237

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of this is that the credentials you provided (username & password) are incorrect or the security group associated with the RDS instance is not allowing connection, i.e. inbound firewall rule.

For your JDBC connection to work, you need to ensure connection can be established on port 3306 (TCP rule).  Check your VPC and security group inbound rules to ensure connections can be established on this port.

You may also find this documentation helpful:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html

Comment: As i have mentioned in my question, the pipeline JDBC connection works 80% of the time but fails intermittently.So credentials and security group is correctly mapped.